# Youtube api V3 live stream get elapsed time since live stream began

Tags: youtube-api, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

According to doc:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information

```
player.getDuration():Number

If the currently playing video is a live event, the getDuration() function will return 
the elapsed time since the live video stream began. Specifically, this is the amount of 
time that the video has streamed without being reset or interrupted. In addition, this 
duration is commonly longer than the actual event time since streaming may begin before 
the event's start time.
```

When I test I get much longer time returned than comparing when I try hovering seekbar youtube and what it returns (for example when hovering youtube seekbar on some video returns 7 hours max, while my API getDuration returns 2000 hours for the same video).  I guess its because:

```
In addition, this 
duration is commonly longer than the actual event time since streaming may begin before 
the event's start time.
```

Using API I can get this (example):

```
 {
"actualStartTime": "2020-03-28T00:20:22Z",
"scheduledStartTime": "2020-03-28T00:19:07Z",
"concurrentViewers": "6125",
"activeLiveChatId": "Cg0KCzM2WW5WOVNUQnFjKicKGFVDaHMwcFNhRW9OTFY0bWV2QkZHYW9LQRILMzZZblY5U1RCcWM"
 }
```

Can I calculate stream actual elapsed time using actualStartTime and scheduledStartTime and how? (so I can have same time as when hovering youtube seekbar)

Otherwise I dont have much use of `getDuration` for live stream.